# Cardinality of the family of all closed subspaces of a separable Banach space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is it true that the cardinality of the family of all closed subspaces of a separable Banach space is less than or equal to continuum ? (or, is countably infinite?)

Thanks for any answer, comment or reference.

Comment: My favourite separable Banach spaces are $\mathbb R^n$ and there are only continuumly many closed subspaces of these spaces. (Fun exercise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all separable Banach spaces are so-called Polish spaces and these only have continuum many Borel sets, even.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are exactly as many closed sets as open sets (taking complements establishes a one-to-one correspondence), so it suffices to determine how many open sets there are.

Each open set is a countable union of open balls (using separability), and there are continuum many open balls, so the number of open sets is at most the number of *sequences of open balls* ("at most", since different sequences of open balls can have the same union), which is---using the fact that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ many open balls---$\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{{\aleph_0}\cdot {\aleph_0}}=2^{\aleph_0}.$ Thus, there are at most continuum many open sets. On the other hand, there are at least continuum many open sets since there are continuum many open balls.